# How to address high volume of low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, homework-and-exercises

[image]

I've noticed that there are an awful lot of people who come here, create new accounts to ask their homework questions, get downvoted and closed then leave.

Obviously, we have flags, we can attempt to edit and we can vote to show that they ARE not suited for physics SE, but I'm concerned that new users will be seeing new users' questions being voted down and closed but THINK that its because they are new and be put off using this site.

Furthermore, I am suggesting that new users see a screen with a "how to make homework style questions into good questions" or "what is / is not on topic" or similar. If there is a lot of information, a lot of people will not read it and will just post, but if there is no guidance then they will of course post anyway.

Comment: _"Furthermore, I am suggesting that new users see a screen with a "how to make homework style questions into good questions" or "what is / is not on topic" or similar."_ You get a tour when you first join.  It also presents the information in a very digestible way IMO.  If a user is putting all the effort into seeing how new users are treated, they should have already put some effort into understanding how the site works.  It's really not clear to me how we would know this is putting people off; we still get a lot of low quality posts and posts from new users.

Comment: I am afraid that new users do like most others on the first page of questions. It takes too long to remove uninteresting questions by throw-away accounts.